# Check if an element is member of a list

Tags: prolog

Basically, I'm trying to create the standard member predicate, in order to avoid having to load modules into my project.

This is my code so far, but unfortunately it isn't working. What am I doing wrong? I even put the cut operator (!) in there to make sure it worked, but it doesn't...

```
/**
* Checks if an element is part of a list
* @param [H|T] List to evaluate
* @param Elem Elem to check
*/
memberCheckSimple([], _):- !, fail.     /* stop condition */
memberCheckSimple([H|T], Elem):-
  Elem \= H,                            /* check if element equals head of list and negate it */
  memberCheckSimple(T, Elem).           /* loop */
memberCheckSimple(_, _).                /* only gets here if Elem belongs to list */
```

Comment: Note that usually, the arguments are: `member(El, Els)`.

Comment: `memberCheckSimple(non_element, non_list)` succeeds

Comment: @false yes I know, but all my project functions are the other way around now, and I'll just mess things up if I try to change them all now. So might as well make it consistent x) Btw, you're on every prolog post I see here on stackoverflow! :p

Comment: *...but unfortunately it isn't working*. Please explain what you've tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: @lurker Just try it, it won't work as intended. memberCheckSimple([a,b,c],d) outputs yes, when it should say no.

Comment: It's not considered a properly stated problem here without some explanation. I see, though, that you have `memberCheckSimple(_, _).` which means `memberCheckSimple/2` will succeed no matter what the arguments are. Prolog doesn't work the way you think, so the comment "only gets here if Elem belongs to list" is not true. It "gets here" eventually on backtracking if other prior options that have a non-zero element list as first argument fail. In Prolog, try to assert what's true, and let what's false fail to match what's true rather than asserting what's false (*e.g.*, your first clause).

Comment: @lurker but how does it get there, if first it goes through the fail? Which even has the cut operator there?

Comment: Have you tried doing a `trace` to watch what happens? You can simplify the example just by testing `memberCheckSimple([a], b).` What you'll find is that, on backtracking, Prolog will retry `memberCheckSimple([a], b).` and succeed on the third clause. Your cut prunes retry of `memberCheckSimple([], _)` but not `[a]` as first argument. Like I said, your logic is failure based. You should make it success based.

Comment: `member(X,[H|T]) :- X=H;member(X,T).`

So this does it, and is commonly available on Internet, and is often used (I believe) in Prolog courses and texts as an example of how to use lists.  Is this not what you need?  If not, why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One primary issue with the logic of your predicate overall is that it is failure based and you are trying to make success be the default of no failure. That's generally the reverse of what you want your logic to be. You want it success based, which is to say, you want to establish facts and rules that describe what's true.

You can play that out as follows. You know that if the element is at the head of the list, that it is an element of the list. So the following is true:

```
memberCheckSimple([H|T], H).   /* H is a member of [H|T] */
```

It's also true that an element is a member of a list if it's a member of the tail of the list:

```
memberCheckSimple([_|T], H) :- memberCheckSimple(T, H).
```

These two rules are really all you need. A query that doesn't match one of the above rules will fail, which is what you want.

Now looking at why your failure based predicate isn't working right and is succeeding in failure cases, it's because of this rule:

```
memberCheckSimple(_, _).
```

This says that anything is a member of anything. You'll have to admit, that doesn't seem logical (because it isn't). Considering your prior clause with the cut:

```
memberCheckSimple([], _) :- !, fail.
```

This prevents backtracking to your "universally true" clause if the first argument is the empty list (`[]`), but not if its non-empty. For example, `memberCheckSimple([a], b)` will eventually fail through a path in which it matches the second clause, and then matches the first clause. But the cut in the first clause doesn't prevent `memberCheckSimple([a], b)` from backtracking (and succeeding) on the third clause. You can observe this by doing a `trace`.

To complete your failure based method (which I'll emphasize again, is the wrong approach to the problem and has other issues, such as not being relational), you'd also need a cut in the second clause:

```
memberCheckSimple([H|T], Elem) :-
  Elem \= H,                    /* check if element equals head of list and negate it */
  !,
  memberCheckSimple(T, Elem).   /* loop */
```

Your comments in the code indicate an imperative thought process. What you call a "loop" is really a "recursion", for example. Also, as was mentioned in another comment, argument ordering is more naturally stated as the element followed by the list since you've named it "member" as opposed to "contains".